# How to capture sys.exit() from subprocesses in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sys

I've created a `master.py` to kick off other scripts.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, run


def main():
    command = ["python3", "file1.py"]
    print("Executing: {}".format(command))
    exit_code, output_string = run_command(command)
    print(output_string)

    command = ["python3", "file2.py"]
    print("Executing: {}".format(command))
    exit_code, output_string = run_command(command)
    print(output_string)

    command = ["python3", "file3.py"]
    print("Executing: {}".format(command))
    exit_code, output_string = run_command(command)
    print(output_string)

    print("Exiting master.py with status_code of {} because {NAME_OF_FILE_THAT_FAILED} failed.")


def run_command(command_to_run):
    result = run(command_to_run, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    return result.returncode, result.stdout.decode()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm trying to capture `sys.exit()` of each sub process script, i.e, capture what `file1.py`, `file2.py` and `file3.py` exited with. If all jobs passed, then the `master.py` will exist with `0` but if at least 1 sub job failed and exited with `1` then I want the master job to exit with 1 as well.

Once it captures the `sys.exit` from all the sub jobs, based on their results, I would like to print that error on the master's final output (the print statement)

Comment: You should already have it in `exit_code`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @kichik

I do see the `exit_code` from the child scripts, however it's not reflecting that on to the master script. How can I achieve that? 

Example: 
if the `exit_code` returned is not `0`, then that should be the status of the master script.

Answer (score 1):

If a subprocess exits with status code 1, the value will be stored `result.returncode`. You can get the error message by also returning `result.stderr.decode()` in `run_command()`

For the behaviour of `master.py` after each child process terminates, I believe you can simply control it using if else statements.